# При оплате в боте не срабатывает фильтр ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

```
#heandlress
async def successfull_payment(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Your payment has been successfully transferred")
    
#main
dp.message.register(successfull_payment, F.content_types == ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени F.content_types == ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT, на F.successful_payment

Comment: dp.message.register(F.successfull_payment)

Is this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: dp.message.register(successfull_payment, F.successfull_payment)

Comment: Hi 
Everything works. 
thank you very much

Comment: Glad to hear it